# Ssh keeps asking for passphrase several times

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, ssh-agent

I have a remote machine, with which I have set up public-key ssh auth - that is, I can ssh to it without typing in password each time. And I have a set of actions in a script, which use that ssh connection.

But when I run that script via cron, it keeps asking passphrase for each action - and since I have more that ten of them, it gets quite boring.

I tried running ssh-add before those actions and got:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

What can I do to reduce number of passphrase retypes?

Comment: Did you add the cron entry to the `crontab` of the user that owns the key? That is, you didn't do something silly like add the script call to the global `crontab`, right?

Comment: @WarrenYoung - actually, that's exactly what I did - I just put in the name of the user that owns the key as  the user to run it from :) What is wrong with it? Crontab treats these two cases different ways?

Comment: Try running `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` before `ssh-add` (and `ssh-agent -k` at end).

Comment: @enzotib - Thanks, it works! I assume that ssh-agent -k should also be placed into eval?

Comment: There is a thing called "necroposting". Can we call what happened today "necromodding"? Come on, the question is 4 (!) years old, don't you have something better to do with your time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

before `ssh-add`, to export the environment variables that refer to the just started agent, then run

```
ssh-agent -k
```

(without `eval`) at end of script to kill the agent.

Comment: When I run a last statement without eval, it gives me back two `unset` statements and an `echo` statement. Isn't it meant to be put into eval?

Comment: @Rogach: it is useful to run it into `eval` when your script keep doing things and you want to unset the variables, but it is not required.